# How to modify an existing AlwaysOn Availability Group IP

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups, failover

I have an unusual question regarding AlwaysOn Availability Group configuration.

I have built out an AOAG cluster on a VM. The build out did not use a Heartbeat network as I had originally requested from our SysOps team. When I did the POC for this HA solution, I tested everything in failing over except what is most important, a true ESX host failure.

I have since proven that the need for the Heartbeat network was necessary and our VM team has built this out with a new IP range.

My question now is what do I need to do to change the IP's for SQL Server to utilize this network? Do I need to uninstall and reinstall SQL Server and configure the AOAG again?

Comment: Are you just trying to add a listener? Did you [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213080.aspx)?

Comment: I'm not trying to add a listener. Basically, the cluster was built on the same ESX host. Now the cluster is going to be on separate ESX Hosts using a Heartbeat Network. I am then moving the SQL VM's to these separate ESX hosts. I will still use the same Listener I had for the original config of the AlwaysOn Availability Group.

Comment: Doesn't DNS take care of this for you? I really don't think you're going to need to uninstall and reinstall SQL Server or start the AG configuration all over again.

Comment: i don't think so. The network doesn't route between ESX hosts.

Comment: So you have AGs on top of an FCI on top of a WSFC which sits on top of an ESX cluster?